# Traffic shaping - Controlling burst time and rate - on Debian server

Tags: debian, traffic-shaping

I run a busy website on a Debian server that utilises Shorewall for most of the traffic management.

**I need to work out a way to shape excess traffic so that all users can burst up to a maximum speed of 1MB/s for say 60 seconds. But any source IP that continues to use that speed past 60 seconds should then be shaped back to 256kb/s, for example.**

This is to slow down **(but not block!)** downloader bots that many of my users like to use to grab huge sections of our asset dirs, but maintain full speed for regular users.

I do not want to have to keep adding useragents to a blacklist as new bot useragents appear often, and some even lie. I just want to shape anything that is using too much bandwidth past a certain amount of time per source IP.

I figure that this can probably be done with Shorewall. However I don't understand how to implement my specific requirement based on their TC docs. I'm one of those people that understands things fast when working backwards from a good example, but detailed technical docs with few relevant examples are not much help for tools with very complex setup.

I'm happy to use any other software that I can install as a package from Debian stable, if there's something better to use than Shorewall for this task.

Thanks!

A

Comment: Why shape traffic? Use an Apache plug-in such as [`mod_security`](http://www.modsecurity.org) & just block the bad behavior.

Comment: We **don't want to block the bots**. We want users to access the data any way they see fit. **We just want to slow them down** if they want to do bulk downloads, while letting all other users have full speed.

Answer (score 0):

Use iptables to match such flows (using hashlimit/limit for example) and then target CLASSIFY. Also create a class in tc (which will be shaped to 256kbit/s), in which you will classify those flows.